# How can I use panelgrid and repeat in a VF page?

Tags: panelgrid

I have used paneldgrid to create a table with VF where field values are fetch from the Lead object.

How can I create a custom controller to query the data base and bring field values from the Lead object that will populate the grid cells?

I need to iterate over the Lead object so is it the best way to do this by using a repeat component? (I want to bring the corresponding field values to Status, Name, Phone, and Comments Line 1)

If anyone can help with some code I would really appreciate it!! thanks!!

Here it's the VF code I have so far:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Lead">
<style>
.colClass{
width:60%;
padding: 5px;
}
.myHeader {
background: #cecece;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<!-- Report Title - Date-->
<apex:panelGrid width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all">
<apex:outputText value="Title- Date"/> 
</apex:panelGrid>

<!-- The table-->
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all">

<!-- Status column -->
<apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block" styleClass="myHeader">
<apex:outputText value="Status"/>
</apex:outputPanel>

<!-- Name - Phone column-->
<apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block" styleClass="myHeader">
<apex:outputText value="Name - Phone"/>
</apex:outputPanel> 

<!-- Status field value -->
<apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block">
<apex:outputText value="{!lead.status}"/> 
</apex:outputPanel> 

<!-- Name - Phone field value-->
<apex:outputPanel style="padding:5px;" layout="block">
<apex:panelGrid width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all">
<apex:outputText value="{!lead.name}"/> 
<apex:outputText value="{!lead.phone}"/> 
</apex:panelGrid> 
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:panelGrid>

<!-- Comments Lines 1-->

<apex:outputText value="Comments Line 1"/>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: sorry code is not found ?Welcome to stackexchange!Could you please post complete code to help with!

Answer (score 1):

A apex:panelGrid will render any apex:repeat elements in a single table cell, and placing apex:panelGrid inside a apex:repeat will render multiple tables. If your goal is one lead per table row, use a apex:dataTable or apex:pageBlockTable. If your goal is several records per row, you'll have to organize your data in the aforementioned tables, perhaps with a wrapper class. apex:panelGrid is designed to lay out non-repeating elements in a HTML table dynamically.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leads}" var="record">
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!record.Name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!record.status}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!record.email}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The difference between apex:dataTable and apex:pageBlockTable is styling/formatting. The former renders as a normal HTML table, while the other renders in a fashion that looks like  a related list (shaded header columns, row highlighting, etc).